# Website showing squares instead of characters?

Tags: html, css

On various pages my website uses characters not found in the standard English language such as " ÿ ä æ ç " and instead of those letters showing all I see is squares and questions marks.

I'm using the font Nueva STD.

Comment: Does the font have those characters in? Does the website specify the correct text encoding? Also is the website anywhere we can see? If so link to it so that we can see the problem in its native form.

Comment: Does that font support your special characters? If it does then you need to set a proper UTF for your page

Comment: are you sure "Nueva" font is installed on your system?

Comment: How do you check the fonts available characters?

Comment: Please show a screenshot. Do you mean you are seeing the [Unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character#Replacement_character), or square squares separately from question marks?

Comment: Nueva® Std is available from Adobe, but I don’t see any note about web usage being permitted. You can of course use it as a “normal font” (as opposite to `@font-face`), but then it will be seen only in computers that happen to have it. If you have a genuine Nueva Std on your computer and you use it as “normal font”, then the problem must be in your HTML or CSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up the font you are using, it seems to have the special characters. If you are using `@font-face` I have had instances where I have to regenerate the files for some reason. That usually fixes it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide an example? It seems like the font you are using doesn't have international characters. Try switching to a default font such as Helvetica and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using the characters directly in the page, have you tried changing them to HTML entities instead? For example, instead of typing ÿ directly, try `&yuml;`.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of properly defining which encoding is used?

Comment: Uhhh... not entirely sure. I guess I may have been taught the wrong way to fix this?